# Relationship between the orbital velocity of a satellite galaxy and its orbital distance

Tags: orbital-motion, dark-matter, galaxy-rotation-curve

Does a satellite galaxy’s orbital velocity decrease with distance from the large galaxy, (similar to planets orbiting a star), or do they orbit faster than expected without invoking dark matter (similar to stars in a galaxy)?

In other words, should we expect the orbital periods of two identical satellite galaxies to be the same or different if they are orbiting at different radial distances?

Comment: I thought that faster than expected rotation meant that dark matter had to be invoked? It seems in your question as if you imply that stars in a galaxy rotate faster than expected without the need to invoke dark matter, or am I reading your question incorrectly?

Comment: If dark matter doesn’t exist then the stars would be orbiting faster than expected. I’m trying to see if there is a uniform orbital velocity for satellite galaxies independent of radial distance, or if they slow down the further they get from the large galaxy.

Comment: So are you looking for an alternative explanation for why stars rotate faster than expected, which does not involve dark matter?

Comment: No, I’m just trying to see what the observational data shows for the orbits of satellite galaxies.

Comment: The orbital speeds of satellite galaxies constrains the distribution of mass and total mass. Most of that mass is dark. I don't really understand your question?

Comment: What is the observed rotation curve of satellite galaxies around the large galaxy? Is it normally a flat rotation curve or do the velocities taper off with distance, as would have been expected by Newton?